# Append div more than one time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/sF5av/1/

i have

```
<div id="anettedata">
     <div class="lbl">Annette Name</div><div class="txt"><input type="text" /></div>
     <input type="button" id="mybtn" class="btnAdd" value="Add Another Annette"  />
</div>
<div id="otheranettedata"></div>
```

and when the "Add Another Annette" click, i want place the same content in the div "anettedata". i have done this using the following jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datatoappend='<div class="otherdata">.........<input type="text" /></div>'
    $('.btnAdd').click(function () {

        $('#otheranettedata').append(datatoappend); // end append        
    });
});
```

[image]

My problem is that when i am again click on the newly created button "Add Another Annette" i want to place the same content below the newly created div. How can i rewrite this jquery and html to solve this problem please help me.

and i have one more question, when add new set of div, how can we remove "Add Another Annette"button from previous ones

Comment: Be aware of that you're adding nodes with the same id as in your Fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation.

The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

Write:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnAdd',function () {         
    $(document).find('.btnAdd').remove();  
    $('#otheranettedata').append(datatoappend); // end append        
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sF5av/6/)

[Refer this document.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: thank you, and i have one more question, when add new set of div, how can we remove "Add Another Annette"button from previous ones

Answer (score 3):

You need to use event delgation

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnAdd', function () {
    $('#otheranettedata').append(datatoappend); // end append        
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sF5av/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for dynamically added elements like,

```
$(document).on('click','.btnAdd',function () {
    $('#otheranettedata').append(datatoappend); // end append        
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sF5av/2/)

**Updated** to remove previously added button try this,

```
$('.btnAdd').length && $('.btnAdd').remove();
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sF5av/7/)

Comment: thank you, and i have one more question, when add new set of div, how can we remove "Add Another Annette"button from previous ones

Comment: just remove button by `$('.btnAdd').remove();`, before appending. Or you can simply append new elements, and use only one button for appending, by keeping the button outside the div.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's .on method, so that it will bind events appended elements too.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnAdd', function () {
    $('#otheranettedata').append(datatoappend);   
});
```

Above code will bind function to all elements with class '.btnAdd' in document.